# Use protected member in operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators

Can you guys help me out solving this simple problem by adding additional , without changing existing code?

```
class ride {
public:
    int km;
};

class moto : protected ride {
public:
    moto(int k) { km = k; };
};

int operator-=(moto m, int km) {
    return m.km - km;
}
```

Comment: there is no protected member.

Comment: Please, explain your problem in a more detailed way.

Comment: code is one of my examples for the class I am taking.. I know the issue is about not being able to access ride protected member. But now I need to solve the issue by adding extra code to this one, with which I currently have an issue

Comment: Learn about `friend`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 _"there is no protected member."_ `moto` inherits from `ride` through `protected` inheritance, so the `km` member is `protected` in the `moto` class.

Comment: Add `friend int operator-=(moto m, int km);` in the `moto` class.

Comment: @Fareanor um right, sorry my mistake

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 There is absolutely no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a member to the `moto` class. Note, as said, that `ride` should not be called a member, it is a base class and `moto` is derived from `ride`.

Because `ride` is a base class of `moto`, `moto` has access to anything in `ride` that is not private. Now I don't know what the assignment says, but it sounds like you are looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
class ride {
public:
    int km;
};

class moto : protected ride {
public:
    moto(int k) { km = k; };
    void operator-= (int in_km) { km -= in_km; }
    int operator()() const { return km; }
};

int main() {
    moto obj(12);
    obj -= 5;
    std::cout << obj() << std::endl;
}
```